# Add jQuery menu a fadeIn and fadeOut

Tags: jquery

I was thinking in making a simple menu with jQuery: Clicking in the menu's items and a div containing information shows up. I want to add a fadeIn and fadeOut of showing up div but i don't know how to achieve this.

this is the code i am using

html:

```
<div id="wrap">
<ul id="divtoggle">
    <li><a id="togglediv1" href="#">show div 1</a></li>
    <li><a id="togglediv2" href="#">show div 2</a></li>
    <li><a id="togglediv3" href="#">show div 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="div1">
    <p>This is the content inside the first container</p>
</div>
<div id="div2">
        <p>This is the content inside the second container</p>
</div>
<div id="div3">
        <p>This is the content inside the third container</p>
</div>
</div>
```

jquery:

```
$("#divtoggle").delegate("a", "click", function(e) {
    var toggled = ($(this).prop("id"));
    $("div#wrap").prop("class", toggled);
});
```

CSS:

```
#div1, #div2, #div3 {
 display:none;   
}
.togglediv1 #div1, .togglediv2 #div2, .togglediv3 #div3{
 display:block;   
}
```

[CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/6rSvf/)

Comment: What's a faceIn? Do you talk about fadeIn?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this (without using css classes):

Markup:

```
<div id="wrap">
    <ul id="divtoggle">
        <li><a id="togglediv1" href="#div1">show div 1</a></li>
        <li><a id="togglediv2" href="#div2">show div 2</a></li>
        <li><a id="togglediv3" href="#div3">show div 3</a></li>
    </ul>
   <div id="content">
        <div id="div1">
            <p>This is the content inside the first container</p>
        </div>
        <div id="div2">
            <p>This is the content inside the second container</p>
        </div>
        <div id="div3">
            <p>This is the content inside the third container</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$("#divtoggle").delegate("a", "click", function(e) {
    var id = ($(this).attr("href"));
    $("#content div").hide("slow");
    $(id).toggle("slow");
});
```

or using the `fadeOut`, `fadeIn` and `fadeToggle` effects:

```
$("#divtoggle").delegate("a", "click", function(e) {
    var id = ($(this).attr("href"));
    $("#content div").fadeOut("slow");
    $(id).fadeToggle("slow");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hescano/6rSvf/256/

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to add fadeIn and fadeOut effects to the .hover mouse events.
[jQuery API .hover()](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)

Comment: You would not need to toggle the divs then.